# How to use show more/hide less toggle for more text with for loop in angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a table whose data coming from loop. When my content text will more than 10 character,'show more' link should come automatically and text length should be reduce.Again when I click 'show more' text should expand to all/remaining characters with 'hide less' link again.Again if I click 'hide less' again return to earlier position.expand/collapse should work individually.Here is the code below

### home.component.html

```
<table>
<tr *ngFor="let items of statusdata"><td>{{items.groupname}} <span>Show more..</span></td></tr>
</table>
```

### home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonserviceService } from './../utilities/services/commonservice.service';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
declare var $: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  statusdata: any;


  ngOnInit() {

      this.statusdata = [{"groupid":1,"groupname":"project1project1project1project1project1project1project1project1project1"},{"groupid":2,"groupname":"project2project1project1project1project1project1project1project1"},{"groupid":3,"groupname":"project3project1project1project1project1project1project1project1project1project1"}];

  }


}
```

Comment: The demo is with 50 character, you can reduce it to 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

.html

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let items of statusdata">
        <td>
            <span *ngIf="!items.showMore">   {{trimString(items.groupname,10)}}</span>
            <span  *ngIf="items.showMore">  {{items.groupname}} </span>
            <div *ngIf="items.groupname.length> 10" (click)="items.showMore = !items.showMore">Show
                <span>{{items.showMore ? 'less' : 'More'}}</span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

.ts

```
   constructor() {
    this.statusdata = this.statusdata.map(item => ({
      ...item,
      showMore:false,
    }));
  }

  trimString(text, length) {
      return text.length > length ? 
             text.substring(0, length) + '...' :
             text;
  }
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ynq7sy?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: why is your binding to innerHTML instead of just normal template interpolation? binding to innerHTML is a dangerous habit to get into

Comment: Thanks @bryan60 It was really out of habit. I will keep it in mind. Modified the code.

Comment: Is there any generic why to do that? Using directive?